# Store odd numbers in array with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create an `array` named `odds` that stores all odd numbers between `-6` and `38` into it using a `for` loop.

```
int[] odds = new int[22];

for (int i = -6, m = 0; i <= 38 && m < 22; i++, m++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        odds[m] = i;
    }
}
```

However is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You increment `m` every time the loop runs. So for `i` = -6 you will store at index 0, but at `i` = -4 you will store at index 2. You are skipping indices. A better method would use the fact that we know every other number is odd, and just increment the loop by 2 every time:

```
int[] odds = new int[22];
for (int i = -5, m = 0; i <= 38; i = i + 2, m++) {
    odds[m] = i;
}
```

Comment: @CyberMaestro happy to help! If this was useful please upvote and accept =]

Answer (score 1):

You are currently allowing the variable `m` which tracks the index for odds in your array to move with the actual value of the odd number.  To remedy this, move the `m` array index counter outside the `for` loop which checks for odds:

```
int[] odds = new int[22];
int m = 0;

for (int i = -6; i <= 38; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        odds[m] = i;
        ++m;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must increase m only if you store a new odd number
So remove the m++ in your for statement and modify your assignment odds[m++] = i;

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use both what Tim and nhouser suggested:

```
int[] odds = new int[22];
int m = 0;
for (int i = -5; i < 38; i += 2) {
  odds[m++] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're increasing `m` on every iteration.

```
int[] odds = new int[22];
int oddCount = 0;
for (int i = -6; i <= 38;i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        odds[oddCount] = i;
        oddCount++;
    }
}
```